# will RegularExpressionAttribute and other validators on Automatic properties work?

Tags: c#, validation, code-generation, xsd2code

I'm using xsd2code for generating classes from schema. how ever I'm suspicious that auto properties can validate values or not?

because if I enable `AutomaticProperties` in xsd2code here is what I get for member with Regex restriction.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="token", AttributeName="color")]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute("#[\\dA-F]{6}([\\dA-F][\\dA-F])?")]
public string Color { get; set; }
```

And when `AutomaticProperties` is disabled

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="token", AttributeName="color")]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute("#[\\dA-F]{6}([\\dA-F][\\dA-F])?")]
public string Color
{
    get
    {
        return this._color;
    }
    set
    {
        System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext validatorPropContext = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(this, null, null);
        validatorPropContext.MemberName = "Color";
        Validator.ValidateProperty(value, validatorPropContext);
        this._color = value;
    }
}
```

It seems these are not equivalent. so I think its a bug in xsd2code or maybe I'm misunderstanding something. whats the purpose of **second** generated code?

I thought `RegularExpressionAttribute` would also validate automatic properties too.